# Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 over Windows RDP on a virtual machine

Tags: upgrade, virtualization, remote-desktop

I tried to upgrade a virtual machine to Ubuntu 18.04 over a remote desktop connection.

Used the command `do-release-upgrade`. Unfortunately the remote desktop connection was interrupted. My guess would be, the upgrade modified `xrdp` which is necessary for a remote desktop connection according to [this article](https://websiteforstudents.com/connect-to-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-desktop-via-remote-desktop-connection-rdp-with-xrdp/).

I can't connect to the virtual machine over SSH as the port is blocked. Is there a way to either get the old version back or to finish the upgrade process?

I need a remote desktop connection in order to work on this server (it's located in a cloud).

Comment: Don't you have a "console" access from the cloud system ?

Comment: I consider your method not good. You do not upgrade cloud instances. You create a new instance and mount your data partition into the new instance with the new OS. If it works you can delete the old instance. Otherwise you re-attach the data partition to the old instance and keep testing.  If your cloud provider does not offer an admin panel and you can get it working from that your instance is gone forever.

Comment: sadly I have no access to the cloud system at all. The cloud is owned by a big company and the policies are very restrictive